# Assign values to columns based on conditions pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, conditional-statements

I am using pyspark to parse large amount of data. I have a dataframe that has the following columns

`ip_address`
`device_id`
`location`
`device_type`

I want to create a new column called `id` and assign the same values of `id` to columns that satisfy one of the following conditions

1) they have the same `device_id` and `ip_address`

2) they have the same `device_id`, `location` and `device_type`

3) they have the same `ip_address`, `location` and `device_type`

Basically, I want to find all those rows that represent the same device based on the above condition, and give them the same id

so lets say I have the following columns

`+--------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| number | device_id | ip_address | location  | device_type |
+--------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|      1 | device1   | ip1        | location1 | type1       |
|      2 | device1   | ip1        | location1 | type1       |
|      3 | device1   | ip2        | location1 | type1       |
|      4 | device2   | ip1        | location1 | type1       |
|      5 | device3   | ip3        | location2 | type2       |
+--------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+`

The first 4 rows should be assigned the same `id` as each row meets one of the three conditions.

row 1 and 2 satisfy condition 1

row 2 and 3 satisfy condition 2

and row 3 and 4 satisfy condition 3

So the output should be

`+--------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+----+
| number | device_id | ip_address | location  | device_type | id |
+--------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+----+
|      1 | device1   | ip1        | location1 | type1       |  1 |
|      2 | device1   | ip1        | location1 | type1       |  1 |
|      3 | device1   | ip2        | location1 | type1       |  1 |
|      4 | device2   | ip1        | location1 | type1       |  1 |
|      5 | device3   | ip3        | location2 | type2       |  2 |
+--------+-----------+------------+-----------+-------------+----+`

Is this even possible to achieve ? and if so how do i go about it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that. Not sure if its the ideal way but it works:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
("1" ,   "device1"   ,   "ip1"        ,  "location1" ,   "type1"),
("2" ,   "device1"   ,   "ip1"        ,  "location1" ,   "type1"),
("3" ,   "device1"   ,   "ip2"        ,  "location1" ,   "type1"),
("4" ,   "device2"   ,   "ip1"        ,  "location1" ,   "type1"),
("5" ,   "device3"   ,   "ip3"        ,  "location2" ,   "type2")
], ("ip_address", "device_id", "location", "device_type"))

df1 = df.groupBy("device_id","ip_address").agg(min(col("number"))).select(col("device_id").alias("d_id"), col("ip_address").alias("ip"), col("min(number)").alias("id1"))
df2 = df.groupBy("device_id","location","device_type").agg(min(col("number"))).select(col("device_id").alias("d_id"), col("location").alias("l"), col("device_type").alias("d_type"), col("min(number)").alias("id2"))
df3 = df.groupBy("ip_address","location","device_type").agg(min(col("number"))).select(col("ip_address").alias("ip"), col("location").alias("l"), col("device_type").alias("d_type"), col("min(number)").alias("id3"))

df.join(df1, [(df1.d_id == df.device_id) & (df1.ip == df.ip_address)], how="inner").select("number","device_id","ip_address","location","device_type","id1").join(df2, [(df2.d_id == df.device_id) & (df2.l == df.location) & (df2.d_type == df.device_type)], how="inner").select("number","device_id","ip_address","location","device_type","id1","id2").join(df3, [(df3.ip == df.ip_address) & (df3.l == df.location) & (df3.d_type == df.device_type)], how="inner").select("number","device_id","ip_address","location","device_type","id1","id2","id3").withColumn("id",least(col("id1"),col("id2"),col("id3"))).show()
```

The join conditions represent your desired conditions. The result is in the final `id` column and looks like:

```
+------+---------+----------+---------+-----------+---+---+---+---+  
|number|device_id|ip_address| location|device_type|id1|id2|id3| id| 
+------+---------+----------+---------+-----------+---+---+---+---+ 
| 5    | device3 | ip3      |location2| type2     | 5 | 5 | 5 | 5 | 
| 3    | device1 | ip2      |location1| type1     | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 
| 4    | device2 | ip1      |location1| type1     | 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 
| 1    | device1 | ip1      |location1| type1     | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 
| 2    | device1 | ip1      |location1| type1     | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 
+------+---------+----------+---------+-----------+---+---+---+---+
```